# How do I disable the PgUp, PgDwn and all these function keys on numpad?

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop-computer

How do I disable the <kbd>PgUp</kbd>, <kbd>PgDn</kbd>, and all these function keys on Numpad ?
I've set up macros on those keys so I need to disable them since the Numpad reads <kbd>9</kbd> as <kbd>PgUp</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd> as <kbd>PgDn</kbd>, <kbd>7</kbd> as <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd> as <kbd>End</kbd> when deactivated.

Comment: You need to edit your question with more details. VirtualKeys don't distinguish between any duplicated keys from numpad. ScanCodes do differentiate between the duplicate keys from numpad..

Comment: So keyboards send scancodes to Windows which .converts them to virtual keys and sends them to programs. Programs can access the underlying scan codes though.

Answer (score 1):

Try the numlock key

When Num Lock is enabled, you can use the numbers on the keypad. When Num Lock is disabled, pressing those keys activates those key's alternate function. For instance, the arrow keys on the keypad may only be used if Num Lock is disabled.

Comment: the software I'm using reads enabled num lock as different keys from disabled num lock, and the macros I've set are for disabled num lock. So I want to disable the alternate functions of the num lock keys.